# Sails.js Waterline Update Method

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I'm using Waterline in my Sails.js App to query my mongo database. I'm able to get a record out based on multiple query paramaters, such as this:

```
Model.findOne({param1: params[0], param2: params[1]})...
```

That works great. I looked at [the docs for `.update()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/update#?example-usage) and copied that but it isn't working. I still need to update a record based on two parameters, so this is my update function:

```
Model.update(
    [{param1: params[0]}, {param2: params[1]}],
    [{field1: update[0]}, {field2: update[1]}]
).exec(function(err, updatedModel) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(updatedModel);
});
```

From what I read, it looks like the first argument to the update method is an object or array of objects with the values you're querying on to update a record; then the second parameter is the updated fields.

I'm not getting an error or an updatedModel, however, which probably means that I'm not finding an object from the Model table in mongo that fits the requirements. But I know that the object is there and the parameters are correct. Any suggestions?

Also, [here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/pjlamb12/0d2738f11759d92415146dc2849bab97) with the update function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Params in `update` function are objects not arrays.

```js
Model.update(
    {param1: params[0], param2: params[1]}, //this is find
    {field1: update[0], field2: update[1]} // this is update
).exec(function(err, updatedModel) {
    if(err)
        console.error(err);
    console.log(updatedModel);
});
```

Comment: I will try this, but the docs say that accepted data types for the find criteria are `{},[{}], string, int` and the updated records accepted types are `{},[{}]`.

Comment: So even though the docs make it appear you can pass an array of objects in the find parameter and the update parameter, you actually can't. Or at least that didn't work. The answer here did work, however.

Comment: Sails documentation have many mistakes. It's build by community right now.